# Sending unique template regions in Mandrill to each recipient

Tags: mailchimp, mandrill, mailchimp-api-v3.0

We have a series of transactional emails in Mandrill (aka MailChimp Transactional) that we need to send to our customers. We can use `merge_vars` to send to multiple recipients at once, but we're also using `mc:edit` in our templates. This means we're making use of `template_content`.

Is there any way to send custom `template_content` to multiple recipients at once? [The documentation](https://mailchimp.com/developer/transactional/docs/templates-dynamic-content/#dynamic-content) doesn't explicitly mention this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible. The best solution is to use `merge_vars` and the added functionality of [Handlebars](https://mailchimp.com/developer/transactional/docs/templates-dynamic-content/#handlebars).